# Vectorize comparisons

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I've written a function which pulls the elements from non-uniform distribution and returns indices of elements of input array, as if they were pulled from uniform distribution. Here is the code and an example:

```
import numpy as np

def uniform_choice(x, n):
    unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    element_freq = np.zeros(x.shape)
    for i in range(len(unique)):
       element_freq[np.where(x == unique[i])[0]] = counts[i]
    p = 1/element_freq/(1/element_freq).sum()
    return np.random.choice(x, n, False, p)

x = np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 100000, p=(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
#so this gives an non-uniform distribution of elements "a", "b", "c", "d"
np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

#returns
(array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='<U1'), 
array([10082, 19888, 30231, 39799]))
```

Using my function I can pull elements from this distribution and get indices as if they were pulled from uniform distribution:

```
np.unique(uniform_choice(x, 5000), return_counts=True)
#returns
array([23389, 90961, 78455, ..., 41405, 22894, 79686])
```

Is it possible to avoid a for loop in my function. I need to do this sampling a lot of times on very large arrays, so this becomes slow. I believe that vectorized version of comparison would give me much faster results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *kill* the loopy portion which I am assuming is the most time consuming part there by extending the use of [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to incorporate `return_inverse=True` that would give us unique numeric labels for each unique string in `x`. Those numeric labels could then be used as indices to lead us to a vectorized calculation for `element_freq`. Thus, the loopy portion -

```
unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
element_freq = np.zeros(x.shape)
for i in range(len(unique)):
   element_freq[np.where(x == unique[i])[0]] = counts[i]
```

would be replaced by -

```
unique, idx, counts = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
element_freq = counts[idx]
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [18]: x = np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 100000, p=(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))

In [19]: %%timeit 
    ...: unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    ...: element_freq = np.zeros(x.shape)
    ...: for i in range(len(unique)):
    ...:    element_freq[np.where(x == unique[i])[0]] = counts[i]
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop

In [20]: %%timeit 
    ...: unique, idx, counts =np.unique(x,return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    ...: element_freq = counts[idx]
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: I never looked at return_inverse, thanks for pointing it out. This is much faster. Thanks.

Comment: @enedene Good to get the confirmation on performance improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (untested):

```
def uniform_choice(x, n):
    unique = np.unique(x)
    values = np.random.choice(x, n, False)
    return np.searchsorted(x, values, sorter=np.argsort(x))
```

This generates `n` values from the unique set, then uses `searchsorted` to look for those values in the original array, and returns their indexes.

The one difference I expect from this approach is that you will only get the first index in `x` where each value appears.  That is, a value which appears in `x` multiple times will always be represented by the index of a single one of its occurrences, whereas in your original code it could be multiple.

Comment: this distinction is important to me. This is a part of a bigger problem, the key is selecting indices as if elements were uniformly distributed. For example, imagine you have lot of articles, and 50% are from sport section 25% from politics, and 25% from entertainment. All articles are unique, and I want to pull 10000 unique articles so that each topic is about 33.33% politics, 33.33% sports and 33.33 entertainment.

Comment: @enedene: In the case you outlined I would do something simpler: first choose the topic randomly, then choose an article on that topic randomly.